# MobyLinuxVM not starting on windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows

Expected behavior
After installing Docker, MobyLinuxVM should be running

Actual behavior
-[x] - During docker install when I opt for windows container, it works, but I see the same above error mentioned about MobyLinuxVM when I try to switch to Linux container.

Information
Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro 
Docker for Windows Version:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker version
Client:
Version: 18.06.0-ce
API version: 1.38
Go version: go1.10.3
Git commit: 0ffa825
Built: Wed Jul 18 19:05:28 2018
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Steps to reproduce the behavior
1. Download and Run 'Docker for Windows Installer.exe', do default installation, I mean don't check for Windows container. I will get installed successfully.
2. Launch Docker for Windows App, You will get the same error
3. I have already enabled HyperV on my window machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the solution and that's really easy. Turn off hyper V in your window machine before installing in docker. Turn on after installing Hyper V and restart your PC. It will solve the problem.